# Get value in province label with highmaps in the highcharter package

Tags: r, highcharts, highmaps

I'm trying to get the value in the province label from this example:

```
library("dplyr")
library('highcharter')
library("viridisLite")

data("USArrests", package = "datasets")
data("usgeojson")

USArrests <- USArrests %>%
  mutate(state = rownames(.))


highchart() %>%
  hc_title(text = "Violent Crime Rates by US State") %>%
  hc_subtitle(text = "Source: USArrests data") %>%
  hc_add_series_map(usgeojson, USArrests, name = "Murder arrests (per 100,000)",
                    value = "Murder", joinBy = c("woename", "state"),
                    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,
                                      format = '{point.properties.postalcode}'))
```

I want to have the value 'Murder' from the USArrests in the dataLabels rather than the state abbr. How should this be done?
Thanks,
Tim

Comment: I think this can help you. https://github.com/jbkunst/highcharter/issues/188

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change dataLabels format you could add map serie like:

```
hc_add_series_map(usgeojson, USArrests, name = "Murder arrests (per 100,000)",
                    value = "Murder", joinBy = c("woename", "state"),
                    dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE,
                                      format = '{point.value}'))
```

Important here is `format = '{point.value}'` - this will make Highcharts use value of a point and a value is set in point from "Murder" (`value = "Murder"`).